# Is there such a word as "lightweightness"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, translation, technical, german

Is there a good translation for the German word "*Leichtgewichtigkeit*" (lit. "lightweightness")?

According to leo.org and dict.cc, there is none, but according to [these translations](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/leichtgewichtigkeit.html), there are several.

What I want to express is that there is "...lightweightness compared to...". I don't want to use the adjective "lightweight" but a noun.

Is there a better choice?

EDIT: I want to describe that an [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) is not as extensive/expensive as others. Thus, *lightness* is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: *Lightweight* can be used as a noun, but only in the sense of a *lightweight* person (either literally or figuratively).

Comment: That's exactly why I'm looking for _lightweightness_ not _lightness_.

Comment: 'Is there a word such as lightweightness?' and 'Is there a good translation for the German word "Leichtgewichtigkeit"' are quite different questions. The best translations are usually not word-for-word. The examples you give in your link are not of consistent accuracy. 1, 5 & 8 are incorrect. Notice that 'lightweight' is a compound adjective whereas 'light weight' is adjective + noun.

Comment: Perhaps "lightness of weight"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lightweight can function both as a noun and an adjective. To describe your API, you could say:

- This API is a lightweight interface with minimal features.

In technical circles, **no-frills** is another term used to describe minimalistic protocols.

- This is a no-frills API with minimal features.

Comment: I think this doesn't meet my requirements since the translation "Leichtigkeit" doesn't match the technical attribute "Leichtgewichtigkeit".

Comment: @my_greets: In English, *light* can mean different things depending on the context. If you are talking of a light balloon, you are referring to the weight (Leichtgewichtigkeit) and if you talk of a *light dance step* , then you refer to *Leichtigkeit*.

Comment: I want to describe that an [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) is not as extensive/expensive as others.

Comment: @my_greets: I have modified my answer now.

Comment: Here you encounter another problem - there is a pejorative sense (and thus often nuance even when not intended) of 'lightweight' (see http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lightweight ) However, the term **is** used in the sense you now indicate you require: _Photoshop Elements V.6, the so-called lightweight version of the more expensive..._ (Google)

Comment: The term ***basic*** is also used to indicate a less complicated, less expensive version of things.

Answer (score 1):

Given that your context is to describe an API is not as extensive/expensive as others, I suggest **simplicity**.

Comment: I think it could be expressed that way too, but in the given context _lightweight_ is definitely more common than _simple_. Seems to me to be some kind of workaround. Can't I use _lightweightness_? Is it an _invalid_ translation?

Comment: To me, *simplicity* has a more positive feel compared to *simple* (probably because *simple* can be used as an insult to mean someone is stupid). If you want to use a form of *lightweight* you should just rearrange the sentence as in Shyam's first example.

Comment: In the official literature such as [RFCs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_Comments), there is always made use of _lightweight_. _Simplicity_ is imprecise in this context.

Comment: @my_greets: No, you can't use _lightweightness_  (if you want to be taken seriously) because English doesn't have an abstract noun corresponding to the adjective _lightweight_. And 'there is always made use of _lightweight_' is ungrammatical; 'the word _lightweight_ is invariably used' is what you require.